# Why idft(dft(a) * dft(b)) not equal to convolve(a, b)?

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, dft

I'm a little confused... I always thought the DFT of a convolution was equal to a product of DFTs, but when I tried this in Python:

```
from scipy import *

a = [1+0j, 2+0j]
b = [4+0j, 5+0j]

print list(ifft(fft(a) * fft(b)))
print list(convolve(a, b))
```

I got back:

```
[(14+0j), (13+0j)]
[(4+0j), (13+0j), (10+0j)]
```

Why are they not the same thing?

Comment: You could just use [fftconvolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html)

Comment: @endolith: That returns the same thing as `convolve`.

Comment: Isn't that what you want?  You're trying to use FFTs to calculate the same output as `convolve`, which is exactly what `fftconvolve` does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficiently calculating autocorrelation using FFTs](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1919/efficiently-calculating-autocorrelation-using-ffts)

Comment: @endolith: I'm not asking *how* to calculate anything; did you read the question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ifft(fft(a) * fft(b))` performs a cyclic convolution, `convolve` apparently zero-pads the inputs. If you pad both arrays with zeros, the result should be the same:

```
a = [0,0,0,1+0j, 2+0j,0,0,0]
b = [0,0,0,4+0j, 5+0j,0,0,0]

print list(ifft(fft(a) * fft(b)))
print list(convolve(a, b))
```

Comment: numpy.core.numeric.convolve uses numpy.core.numeric.multiarray.correlate (correlation via shifted dot products) with the 2nd array time reversed. It doesn't use the FFT, so it preserves the array type according to the highest priority of the two arrays, as long as the type has a dot function defined.