# minimal signal window size (length)

Tags: window

In order to detect a frequency component of 1 Hz with a DFT - do I need a signal window (signal in time domain) of at least 1 second length (in order to have at least 1 cycle of the desired minimal frequency I want to detect)?

Or is it possible to evaluate the spectrum of low frequencies with short signal windows (in seconds - independent of sampling frequency)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect a frequency with a *DFT*, yes, you'll need an integer number of signal periods in your observation. The smallest useful integer is 1.

On the other hand, why use the DFT to detect a single frequency? Aside from the obvious "use Goertzel if you only care about a single frequency", which would only lead you to a filter of the same length as said DFT, you could use one of many parametric and non-parametric frequency estimators.

A simple low- or bandpass-filter might totally do it, depending on your application!

Other estimators for when you know where you want to evaluate the spectrum include the MUSIC algorithm (which can be *really* low complexity if you know there's exactly one tone in your signal, and you know your SNR is OK), or very simple fast segmented autocorrelation methods.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :-)

Could you give me a hint where I find more info on the autocorrelation methods you mentioned? Some keywords to help me move ahead.

Comment: "fast autocorrelation", really, and then look for max_index(abs(autocorrelation)))

Comment: @Andreas AFAIK, fast autocorrelation or cross-correlation is implemented by using FFT. Check here [Efficiently calculating autocorrelation using FFTs](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1919/efficiently-calculating-autocorrelation-using-ffts)